UUID vs Long primary key
In database design, when considering a primary key, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using UUID compared to a Long data type?
I came across two different tutorials that implemented each of them, and I am just curious about which one serves better.

I can't really think of any advantages to using a 36 character key versus a primitive long other than maybe allowing for a larger key domain.  The performance hit for key storage and queries using string comparison doesn't really make sense to me.

@MichaelKrause I would hope that UUIDs are stored in 16 bytes and only converted to strings for display.

@MichaelKrause A typical advantage of UUIDs over numbers is, that they are not predictable. Ie if you have IDs 3 and 5, the chances are high, there is also an ID 2 or 4, which you might not want everybody to know. This might be irrelevant in some cases, but important in others ...

The biggest advantage of a GUID as a key column is that you can create them in distributed systems without a round trip to the database

Compare UUID and Long as the type of primary key in database:
1. Long:

Long or BigInt is 64-bit, less than UUID (128-bit).

Long is faster to generate, always generate unique ID, but not random. For example, in Spring Boot:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;



This code will generate an increasing-from-0 key. For example:
0, 1, 2, .... Of course, an increasing-from-0 key won't be safe against something like XSS (because of its easy-to-predict property).
2. UUID:

UUID is 128-bit, more than Long (64-bit).
Like Long, UUID always generate unique ID (like 558012d6-7db5-4053-b838-6a1ef4ad019b), but it's random, a bit slower and much harder to predict. This means it's more secure than Long.

In summary, both are good to use as the primary key in database. I think UUID is better, but I prefer to use Long because it's easier to implement in the program.

Using a Long doesn't mean you have to use a sequence value. You can use a secure random value or calculate a hash from a natural key (if you have one). For me the real question is whether you think a range of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 values (max unsigned Long) is enough for your use case, or you want to stick with generated ids.

I would say it depends:)
Longs are better for performance. They are smaller, it's easier to handle indexes for them on the DBA side, less chance to conflict, and easier to debug.
On the other hand, using Long disclose some information on you system. How much data you have etc, which can be used by potential bad actors.
So if you care for security over performance, go with UUID.
So I would say everything depends what you are building, if you are building system that is exposed to 3rd parties, go with UUID, if you building something internal feel free to use numeric ids
